# How to call method Reference in map

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

> I create a class ApUtils . Define two methods in that class . I want
> use that two methods in my service class inside the map function by
> the help of method reference ,But I am getting un excepted error while
> calling these two methods
> service.kt

```
package com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.services

import com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.Utils.AppUtils
import com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.dto.ProductDto
import com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.entity.Product
import com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.repository.ProductRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono


@Service
class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var productRepository: ProductRepository
    fun getProduct():Flux<ProductDto>{
        return productRepository.findAll().map(obj: AppUtils -> obj.entityToDto(product))
    }
    fun getProduct(id:String):Mono<ProductDto>{
        return productRepository.findById(id).map{ obj: AppUtils, product: Product -> obj.entityToDto(product) }
    }
}
```

> AppUtils.kt

```
package com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.Utils

import com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.dto.ProductDto
import com.nilmani.reactivespringdemo.entity.Product
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils

class AppUtils {
    fun entityToDto(product: Product):ProductDto{
        val productDto = ProductDto()
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(product,productDto)
        return productDto
    }
    fun dtoToEntity(productDto: ProductDto):Product{
        val product = Product()
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(productDto,product)
        return product
    }
}
```

How to call these two function in my service class using method reference

Answer (score -1):

If you change `AppUtils` to a singleton using Kotlin's `object` keyword:

```
object AppUtils { ... }
```

then you can use method references like so:

```
fun getProduct(id:String) = productRepository.findById(id).map(AppUtils::entityToDto)
```